# Using two external monitors with a laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell-studio

I have a dell studio 1558, it has one HDMI and one VGA connection.

I am able to connect and detect both of them (one on HDMI and one of VGA) at the same time, but I can't get a picture to both. I tried everything, but I can't find any way to do it.

Comment: Is this with the lid closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most laptop GPU's don't allow both at the same time. You can try looking in the BIOS settings (look for something related to primary/secondary video output), but it's not likely.

Comment: After some more searching it seems you are correct. I'll see if I can get something to connect to it then use synergy.